# How can I get CMake to automatically detect the value for CUDA_ARCHITECTURES?

Tags: cmake, cuda, nvidia, build-automation, compute-capability

Newer versions of CMake (3.18 and later), are "aware" of the choice of CUDA architectures which compilation of CUDA code targets. Targets have a [`CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html#prop_tgt:CUDA_ARCHITECTURES) property, which, when set, generates the appropriate `-gencode arch=whatever,code=whatever` compilation options for you. You will even get a warning if you don't set this value:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is empty for target "my_cuda_app".
```

by default, this target property is initialized to [`CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html#variable:CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES). But `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` itself is not initialized to anything (!)

How can we have CMake auto-detect an appropriate value for `CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` or the global `CMAKD_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`? That is, use the architectures of GPUs installed on the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CMake actually offers such autodetection capability, but:

1. It's undocumented (and will probably be refactored at some point in the future).
2. It's part of the deprecated FindCUDA mechanism, and is geared towards direct manipulation of `CUDA_CMAKE_FLAGS` (which isnt what we want).
3. It doesn't "play nice", and hides its useful-form internal variables from us.

Still, with a little elbow grease, we can make it work.

First, its location: It's in a module, `FindCUDA/select_compute_arch` (which, on a Linux system, will be located in `/path/to/cmake/root/share/cmake-X.YY/Modules/FindCUDA/select_compute_arch.cmake`).

Now here's how you use it:

```
include(FindCUDA/select_compute_arch)
CUDA_DETECT_INSTALLED_GPUS(INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_1)
string(STRIP "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_1}" INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_2)
string(REPLACE " " ";" INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_3 "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_2}")
string(REPLACE "." "" CUDA_ARCH_LIST "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_3}")
SET(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES ${CUDA_ARCH_LIST})
```

If you only want this for a single target, you would replace the last line with:

```
set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY "${CUDA_ARCH_LIST}")
```

Notes:

- When there are *no* GPUs on your system you may get a result such as: `3.5;5.0;5.3;6.0;6.1;7.0;7.5;7.5+PTX`.

  This is an [issue with CMake which will not be resolved](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22386), since the submodule we're using here is not officially supported. So, if you need to compile on systems with no GPUs, either avoid this call or parse your results for the "+PTX" entry.
- The `select_compute_arch` submodule has existed for much longer, but in the past you would use it differently, and would include it through `include(FindCUDA)`.
- I wonder if `LIST(APPEND CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` might not be more appropriate than `SET(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`.
- See CMake issues [22375](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22375) and [19199](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19199) for where CMake might go with this in the future. Caveat: I filed those bugs...

Comment: `set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY "${CUDA_ARCH_LIST}")` (with quotes) may work a bit better because if the variable is empty it produces a hard syntax error.

Comment: This didn't work for me in a system with CMake 3.13, I had to use ` cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags(ARCH_FLAGS "Auto")` for that system, which doesn't work for later versions of CMake (e.g. 3.16). See my ohter answer.

Answer (score 11):

In the upcoming CMake 3.24, you will be able to write:

```
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES native)
```

and this will build target `tgt` for the (concrete) CUDA architectures of GPUs available on your system at configuration time.

With newer versions of CUDA (11.5 and later), the will pass `native` on to nvcc and other executables; with older versions, it will auto-detect which architectures are the 'native' ones.

**Caveat:** This does not actually give you the list of architectures (e.g. to iterate in your CMake code.)

Answer (score 4):

I had problems using the other solution with a system with CMake 3.13, not sure what it is but I had to use this.

There is probably a better way to do this.

```
    if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS_EQUAL "3.13.4")
      cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags(ARCH_FLAGS "Auto") # optional argument for arch to add
      message("ARCH_FLAGS = ${ARCH_FLAGS}")
      string(REPLACE "-gencode;" "--generate-code=" ARCH_FLAGS "${ARCH_FLAGS}")
      string(APPEND CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${ARCH_FLAGS}")
    else()
      include(FindCUDA/select_compute_arch)
      CUDA_DETECT_INSTALLED_GPUS(INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_1)
      string(STRIP "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_1}" INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_2)
      string(REPLACE " " ";" INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_3 "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_2}")
      string(REPLACE "." "" CUDA_ARCH_LIST "${INSTALLED_GPU_CCS_3}")
      SET(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES ${CUDA_ARCH_LIST})
      set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "${CUDA_ARCH_LIST}")
    endif()
```

Answer (score 4):

I typically do this on the `cmake` command line, e.g.:

```
$ export CUDACXX="/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc"
$ cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=native -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Comment: I meant automatically within CMake. I can't rely on users doing manual work before invoking CMake...