# CUDA atomicAdd_block is undefined

Tags: cuda, gpu-atomics, compute-capability

[According to CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions), "Atomic functions are only atomic with respect to other operations performed by threads of a particular set ... Block-wide atomics: atomic for all CUDA threads in the current program executing in the same thread block as the current thread. These are suffixed with _block, e.g., `atomicAdd_block`"

However, I cannot use `atomicAdd_block` while my code is compiled fine with `atomicAdd`. Is there any header or library that I should add or link to?

Comment: What CUDA version are you using? What's your GPU's Compute Capability?

Comment: Thanks, do you know when the new function was introduced? I am using 11.4

Comment: Actually, I changed my comment; it might also be that your GPU does not support them.

Comment: My device is  Tesla V100, so the compute capability is 7.0

Comment: You need to specifically compile for compute capability 6.0 or higher.  So try adding `-arch=sm_70` on your `nvcc` compile command line, to match your V100 GPU.

Comment: From [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions): "Devices with compute capability less than 6.0 only support device-wide atomic operations"  so to enable that feature you  have to specifically compile for a cc6.0 device or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atomicAdd()` has been supported for a long time - by earlier versions of CUDA and with older micro-architectures. However, `atomicAdd_system()` and `atomicAdd_block` were introduced, IIANM, with the Pascal micro-architecture, in 2016. The minimum Compute Capability in which they are supported [is 6.0](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions). If you're targeting CC 5.2 or earlier - or if your CUDA version is several years old - then they might not be available to you.

This is actually likely to be the case, since even for the current version of CUDA, nvcc will default to Compute Capability 5.2 if no other value is specified with `-gencode` or `-arch` (e.g. if you run `nvcc -o out my_file.cu`).

Answer (score 1):

As Robert said, the solution is to add `-arch=sm_70` in compile or for those who use CMake is to add `set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 70)` to their CMakeLists.txt

Comment: It is inappropriate to hard-code features of the *system you're building on* into a `CMakeLists.txt` file, which represents requirements of the *project being built*.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you have any solution to make it more portable?

Comment: A proper solution is not yet available in CMake. But, for now, read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68223398/1593077) of mine.

Comment: ... and you're reminded me to file [this CMake issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22839) :-)