# Building a simple CUDA program with clang++ and CMake

Tags: cmake, cuda, clang, clang++

I am trying to compile a simple `.cu` file using `clang++` instead of `nvcc`, although basic instructions have been provided by the [LLVM documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html), I have been struggling with the various CMake specifications i.e do I need to specify the `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER`, `CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES` etc. Currently I cannot build or compile the `.cu` file.

I have tried various CMake specifications but it seems to be a shot in the dark and a guessing game really.

Comment: Please include what you have tried, i.e. a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what errors you got.

Comment: Crossposting: [Clad GitHub Issue](https://github.com/vgvassilev/clad/issues/711#issuecomment-1907868980)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple - with recent versions of CMake and clang. Consider a single-`.cu` file executable (e.g. NVIDIA's [vectorAdd example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/vectorAdd), assuming you've placed all of the relevant include files in the same directory as `vectorAdd.cu`). This CMakeLists file works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(vector_addition_with_clang CUDA)

add_executable(vectorAdd vectorAdd.cu)
set_target_properties(vectorAdd PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES native)
```

Now, configure using:

```
cmake \
    -B /path/to/build/dir \
    -DCMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/path/to/clang++ \
    -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/path/to/clang++
```

and I've verified this works with CMake version 3.27 and 3.28, and with clang 16.

*Note:* Remember to completely delete your build directory, or at least the `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles/` directories, before every configuration attempt. Earlier failures can mess up future attempts which would otherwise work.

---

#### Older versions of CMake

If you use a CMake version earlier than 3.24, you can't say `native`, you have to use a concrete value, or use a bit of automatic detection CMake  voodoo as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223399/1593077). Even older versions of CMake may exhibit other problems. 3.20 works, but 3.18 has trouble passing CMAKE_ARCHITECTURES properly to clang.

#### Older versions of clang

clang 14 will fail for some reason - not sure why - even with newer CMake. I get:

```
CMake Error at /path/to/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:603 (message):
  Failed to detect a default CUDA architecture.

  Compiler output:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

not sure why. I've [filed a bug about this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25637) with KitWare. Haven't tried clang 15 - readers are encouraged to try and comment.